# Python Numpy : operands could not be broadcast together with shapes when producting matrix

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
def grams(A):
    (m,n) = A.shape
    Q = A
    R = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        R[i,i] = np.linalg.norm(Q[:,i])
        Q[:,i] =Q[:,i]/R[i,i]
        R[i,i+1:n] = np.transpose(Q[:,i])*Q[:,i+1:n]
        Q[:,i+1:n] = Q[:,i+1:n+1]-Q[:,i]*R[i,i+1:n]
    R[n,n] = np.linalg.norm(Q[:,n])
    Q[:,n] = Q[:,n]/R[n,n] 
    return Q, R
A = np.array( [[1,1,2],[4,3,1],[1,6,6]] )
print grams(A)
```

The error is on the line

```
R[i,i+1:n] = np.transpose(Q[:,i])*Q[:,i+1:n]
```

The error is

```
ValueError:
    operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,2)
```

Comment: In which line is the error happening? Some whitespace between operators and commas could make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Lets recreate this in a small case

```
In [105]: n=4
In [106]: m,n=2,4
In [107]: Q=np.arange(m*n).reshape(m,n)
In [108]: R=np.zeros((n,n))
```

So for one step, the target is a (3,) slot in `R`

```
In [109]: i=0
In [110]: R[i,i+1:n]
Out[110]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
In [111]: Q[:,i]
Out[111]: array([0, 4])
In [112]: Q[:,i+1:n]
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

One array is (m,), the other (m,3).  The only way to combine them and produce (3,) is with a `dot` (using last/only dim of one, and 2nd last dim of the other):

```
In [113]: np.dot(Q[:,i],Q[:,i+1:n])
Out[113]: array([20, 24, 28])
```

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk `*` performs **elementwise multiplication** in `numpy`. Your code reads:

```
R[i,i+1:n] = np.transpose(Q[:,i])*Q[:,i+1:n]
```

`np.transpose(Q[:,i])` has dimensions `(3, 1)` and `Q[:,i+1:n]` `(3, 2)`, so they cannot be elementwise multiplied together as dimensions don't match.

I suspect you may want to multiply `np.transpose(Q[:,i])` and `Q[:,i+1:n]` using **matrix multiplication**, in that case you can use `numpy.dot` as follows:

```
R[i,i+1:n] = np.dot(np.transpose(Q[:,i]), Q[:,i+1:n])
```

but dimensions don't match for matrix multiplication either, so your algorithm's implementation is probably wrong somewhere before that line.

Comment: `Q[:,i]` has shape (3,), and `transpose` does not change that.